# DDL comments directly when creating schema objects

Tags: oracle, ddl

Is it possible to do this in a single query:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(bar INTEGER);

COMMENT ON foo IS 'my foo table';

COMMENT ON bar IS 'my bar column of the foo table';
```

Something like for the constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
           ( bar INTEGER COMMENT IS 'my bar column of the foo table'
           , COMMENT IS 'my foo table'
           );
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [COMMENT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4009.htm) is an Oracle statement and has to be issued seperately to the `CREATE TABLE` command.

There is a similar question asked on the Oracle Forums [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4513885&tstart=0).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was afraid this would be what you tell.

Answer (score 0):

NO.. you cannot include Comments while defining the Objects..
you can do it once the object is created..